# Android Rotation around alternate axis using matrix

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I'm using the `matrix.rotate(deg, fx,fy)` method to rotate an image.

The image has an `alpha` channel and only has something visual in the right-hand corner. I want to rotate the canvas, create the new image with that `matrix` and have the visual part be the only part that is rotating.

At the moment the image rotates but doesn't rotate around the desired `axis`. It always rotates around the original width of the object.

Here is the code I use:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

matrix.setRotate(rotation, xPivot, yPivot);
Bitmap pic1a = Bitmap.createBitmap(pic1, 0, 0, pic1.getWidth(), pic1.getHeight(), matrix, true);
```

This rotates the image correctly but only seems to rotate within the same location of the original canvas. 
What I want is for the point that the image rotates around (xPivot, yPivot) becoming the centre location on the display.

Comment: I think I might be able to help assuming I'm reading your problem correctly. You have an image that is mostly blank that you draw at the location `(x,y)` which you need to rotate by `q` degrees. You want to re-draw the new bitmap rotated at a different axis? Can you post your code block where you calculate and execute the change?

Comment: Do i need to work the matrix together with the canvas?